# Hazelcast Cluster Map Configuration

Tags: java, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I have a cluster with two members and one map. This map has an eviction policy configured. Is this configuration locally or it will be considered to the whole cluster?

In case of cluster wide configuration, when I deploy a new member it will overwrite map configuration? And does lite members overwrite those configurations?

Answer (score 1):

> Is this configuration locally or it will be considered to the whole
>   cluster?

Eviction policy for an IMap is a cluster-wide configuration for its entries.

> In case of cluster wide configuration, when I deploy a new member it
>   will overwrite map configuration? And does lite members overwrite
>   those configurations?

Any new members would pickup the existing configurations itself. Doesn't matter if it's a lite member.
Also, changing the map configuration on the fly feature is not yet available so once it is up, it will continue to work with the initial configurations itself.

Comment: thanks A.Desai, did you found any documentation regarding this topic? I couldn't find any of those information.

Comment: Through personal experience of working in Hazelcast. It is not explicitly mentioned in the documentation, but if you look at the IMap documentation, you can understand it. It has been discussed multiple times in lot of forums though.

Answer (score 0):

Eviction policy is per partition.
See hazelcast documentation:
http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.5/manual/html/map-eviction.html

> Assume that you have the following figures:
>
> Partition count: 200 
>   Entry count for each partition: 100 max-size
>   (PER_NODE): 20000 eviction-percentage (please see Configuring Map
>   Eviction): 10% The total number of entries here is 20000 (partition
>   count * entry count for each partition). This means you are at the
>   eviction threshold since you set the max-size to 20000. When you try
>   to put an entry:
>
> Entry goes to the relevant partition. Partition checks whether the
>   eviction threshold is reached (max-size). If reached, approximately 10
>   (100 * 10%) entries are evicted from that particular partition. As a
>   result of this eviction process, when you check the size of your map,
>   it is ~19990 (20000 - ~10). After this eviction, subsequent put
>   operations will not trigger the next eviction until the map size is
>   again close to the max-size.